# What type of database field for a multiple choice Search filter with DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What type of Database field is the most efficent one for a drf based search filter? I'm trying to build a search feature where i can search by a specific set of features. You could compare it to an hotel search were you filter by Amenities that you want.
Are many to many fields the best choice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest many to many fields:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```